Tkinter: Blank window when i use tk.Toplevel(), but when i dont use tk.Toplevel "pyimageN doesn't exist"
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox
import tela_inicial

def tela_de_login():
    def verificar_login():
        usuario = caixa_usuario.get()
        senha = caixa_senha.get()
        if (usuario == 'Nicolas' and senha == '54321') or (usuario == 'Baliana' and senha == '1456') or (usuario == 'Gustavo' and senha == '12345'):
            messagebox.showinfo('Sucesso', 'Logado!')
            root.destroy()
            tela_inicial.abrir_telainicial()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Erro', 'Usuário errado')

    def mostrar_senha():
        if caixa_senha['show'] == '*':
            caixa_senha.configure(show='')
            botao_mostrar_senha.configure(image=imagem_olho)
        else:
            caixa_senha.configure(show='*')
            botao_mostrar_senha.configure(image=imagem_olhofechado)

    # Criação da janela
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Tela de Login')

    largura_janela = 900
    altura_janela = 550

    largura_tela = root.winfo_screenwidth()  # Tamanho da tela
    altura_tela = root.winfo_screenheight()

    x_pos = (largura_tela - largura_janela) // 2  # Duas barras para retornar um número inteiro
    y_pos = (altura_tela - altura_janela) // 2

    root.geometry(f'{largura_janela}x{altura_janela}+{x_pos}+{y_pos}')  # Largura, altura, posição da tela
    root.resizable(False, False)
    # Fundo
    imagem_fundo_caminho = (fr'imagens\fundo.png')
    imagem_fundo_arquivo = Image.open(imagem_fundo_caminho)
    imagem_fundo_arquivo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagem_fundo_arquivo)
    imagem_fundo = tk.Label(root, image=imagem_fundo_arquivo2)
    imagem_fundo.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


    # Logo
    imagem_logo_caminho = Image.open(fr'imagens\logo.png')
    imagem_logo_arquivo = imagem_logo_caminho
    largura = 300
    altura = 300
    imagem_logo_arquivo = imagem_logo_arquivo.resize((largura, altura))
    imagem_logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagem_logo_arquivo)
    root.imagem_logo = imagem_logo  # Manter a referência
    label_imagem = tk.Label(root, image=imagem_logo, bg='white')
    label_imagem.place(relx=0.505, rely=0.18, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # Olho aberto (mostrar senha)
    imagem_olho_caminho = (fr'imagens\olho.webp')  # Alterar caminho dependendo de onde a imagem está
    imagem_olho = Image.open(imagem_olho_caminho)
    imagem_olho = imagem_olho.resize((30, 30))  # Ajuste de tamanho
    imagem_olho = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagem_olho)
    root.imagem_olho = imagem_olho  # Manter a referência

    # Olho fechado (não mostrar a senha)
    imagem_olhofechado_caminho = (fr'imagens\fechado.png')
    imagem_olhofechado = Image.open(imagem_olhofechado_caminho)
    imagem_olhofechado = imagem_olhofechado.resize((30, 30))  
    imagem_olhofechado = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagem_olhofechado)
    root.imagem_olhofechado = imagem_olhofechado  # Manter a referência

    # Textos e caixas para colocar login
    texto_login = tk.Label(root, text='LOGIN', fg='black', bg='white', font=('Trebuchet MS', 24, 'bold'))
    texto_login.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.40, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    pedir_login_texto = tk.Label(root, text='Insira seu nome:', font=("Calibri", 13), fg='black', bg='white')
    pedir_login_texto.place(relx=0.348, rely=0.50, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    caixa_usuario = tk.Entry(root, bg='white', fg='black')
    caixa_usuario.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.50, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    pedir_senha_texto = tk.Label(root, text='Insira sua senha:', font=("Calibri", 13), fg='black', bg='white')
    pedir_senha_texto.place(relx=0.350, rely=0.55, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    caixa_senha = tk.Entry(root, show='*', bg='white', fg='black')
    caixa_senha.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.55, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # Botão para mostrar a senha
    botao_mostrar_senha = tk.Button(root, image=imagem_olhofechado, command=mostrar_senha, height=30)
    botao_mostrar_senha.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.525, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # Botão de login
    botao_login = tk.Button(root, text='Iniciar', command=verificar_login, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'), bg='white', fg='black')
    botao_login.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tela_de_login()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\nicol\OneDrive\Documentos\pasta de pastas\programação\Site Petshop\mainlogin.py", line 100, in <module>
    tela_de_login()
  File "c:\Users\nicol\OneDrive\Documentos\pasta de pastas\programação\Site Petshop\mainlogin.py", line 44, in tela_de_login
    imagem_fundo = tk.Label(root, image=imagem_fundo_arquivo2)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3237, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2648, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist


My program has more than one window, and it was working well but then this "pyimageN" error started to appear and i resolved it using tk.Toplevel, but then creates a "Tela de Login" empty window with my original window.
The code I presented is the main code, where i start my program. if necessary i can show all my codes

@JRiggles there it is

Typo: fr'imagens\pundo.png' should be fr'imagens\fundo.png' ?

@e-motta no, its really "pundo" (fiquei com preguiça de mudar o arquivo de nome e deixei assim mesmo)

it is certainly not a typo, changed the names to not make it confusing

Try adding master=root to all tk.PhotoImage().

@TheLizzard ohh it really worked, but the empty window still appear when i start the code. i can close it now with the program still working, but can the window just doesnt exist?

It worked for me without fr.
